# Want to change header of exported file in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Greetings,

I am working on symfony sonata admin and i am using its default export functionality.

my database column name is phonecode so when i export file the header name is called as phonecode.

I want to change it dynamically , i dont want to change column name because it is used everywhere in the project .

Is there any way where i want this type of output .

```
name    phonecode
parth    +91
test     +444
```

to

```
name    country code
parth    +91
test     +444
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the getExportFields as already mentioned but use an array to map the names ... the key is the column caption ...

```
public function getExportFields()
{
    $dynamicColumnCaption = ...;

    return array($dynamicColumnCaption => 'phonecode', 
                 'anotherColumnCaption' => 'columnName');
}
```

Comment: It's Working Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You can override `getExportFields()`method.

```
public function getExportFields()
{
    return array('name', 'countrycode');
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  there are two fields there and i am returning array of both at the same time . I want name but in place of phonecode i need country code.